# Return results in a nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through the `req.body` that has data and I am trying to return the `bookStatus` of all the books present inside the body. I am doing this:

```
let bod = req.body.books;
const filtered = bod.map(function (rep){
        console.log(rep);
        return rep.bookStatus;
    });
```

This returns the `bookStatus` of all the books, but it is just the value of the `bookStatus` key. I am trying to get the key as well, for it to look like `{bookStatus:"value"}`.

UPDATE:
solution posted by @evolutionxbox works, except now I am trying to access only the ones that have the status published. I am doing this:

```
if(rep.bookStatus === 'published') {
 return ({ bookStatus: rep.bookStatus })
}
```

But this returns the results as following `[ { bookStatus: 'published' }, { bookStatus: 'published' }, undefined ]`. Here `undefined` is the `unpublished` one but I do not even want it to be there in first place

Comment: You must then return an object `return ({ bookStatus: rep.bookStatus })`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox how do I also make sure to return just the ones with `bookStatus` value as published? I did this inside an if condition but it still returns the unpublished ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let bod = req.body.books;
const filtered = bod.map(function (rep){
        console.log(rep);
        return { bookStatus : rep.bookStatus };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let bod = req.body.books;

const filtered = bod.map(function ({bookStatus}){
    console.log(rep);
    return {bookStatus};
});
```

Comment: this does not make sense

Comment: @boomchickawawa this is called destructuring

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: solution posted by @evolutionxbox works, except now I am trying to access only the ones that have the status published. I am doing this:

```
if(rep.bookStatus === 'published') {
 return ({ bookStatus: rep.bookStatus })
}
```

But this returns the results as following `[ { bookStatus: 'published' }, { bookStatus: 'published' }, undefined ]`. Here `undefined` is the `unpublished` one but I do not even want it to be there in first place

Comment: What about filtering before mapping? `bod.filter(rep => rep.bookStatus)`